# ¿Como puedo capturar mi IP con javascript?

Tags: javascript, ip

Tengo una aplicación de manera local y ya que no tengo dominio necesito saber la IP del servidor desde javascript, mi aplicación comparte archivos por link y el link empieza por https://192..../link.php

Necesitaria saber la ip local del servidor mediante javascript

Comment: ¿Quieres saber la IP del servidor que has tecleado en la URL? ?Túg generas esos enlaces o te los dan generados? ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor el proceso completo para tener una visión general de qué controlas y qué no? ¿Has probado con [`document.location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hostname)?

Answer (score 1):

Echa un vistazo a [esta](https://ipstack.com/) pagina

```js
$.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(info) {
  console.log(info);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Desde esta pagina puedes consultar direcciones

Answer (score 0):

Ignoro lo que estás haciendo, pero no suena muy buena idea querer capturar la IP para ir a rescatar algo desde el servidor. Deberías seguir usando el nombre de dominio que pretendes usar. En caso de que no tengas un dominio todavía, podrías forzar a que tu sistema operativo resuelva el dominio que necesites.

Para eso tienes que editar el archivo hosts. Ahí debes agregar el nombre del dominio y la IP que resuelve:

> 192.168.0.1 midominio.com

En linux está en /etc/hosts y en windows C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\
Para ambos casos necesitas permiso de roott/administrador respectivamente.
Ten en cuenta que esta solución solo funcionará en TU computador. Si quieres compartir el cambio con alguien más en tu red, debes indicarle que haga la misma configuración que tu.

Comment: A ver no hay problema ya que se trata de mi proyecto final de curso, entonces lo que necesito es saber que ip tiene mi servidor con javascript, la ip local. Si cambio de red quiero que el enlace que me devuelva contenta la IP que tiene en ese momento el servidor

Comment: Si es que nadie más va a usar tu computador, puedes escribir 127.0.0.1 midominio.com
Así te aseguras que cada vez que entres a midominio.com todo funcione de acuerdo a lo esperado.